# How to remove punctuations in a dictionary

Tags: string, python-3.x, punctuation

I have a dictionary where key is string and values are a list of strings. I tried to remove the punctuations using `strings.punctuations` from `import strings` module.

```
>>> dat = {'2008':['what!','@cool','#fog','@dddong'],'2010':['hey','@cute']}
>>> 

>>> def remove_punct(data):
...     import string
...     punct = string.punctuation
...     rpunct = punct.replace('@',"") # withold @
...     for k,v in data.items():
...         for word in data[k]:
...             word = word.strip(rpunct)
...     return data
... 
>>> remove_punct(dat)
{'2008': ['what!', '@cool', '#fog', '@dddong'], '2010': ['hey', '@cute']}
```

Why won't I get the result with # and ! removed?

Do I have to define the dictionary again, after `word.strip(rpunct)`...?

Comment: Add a print statement `print(data[k])` after `word = word.strip(rpunct)` to see what happens. The issue is you are trying to modify a list in a loop. If you google that you will find many questions and work-arounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually modifying `data`. You need to either directly modify `data` or create a new dictionary and fill this with the new data:

```
>>> dat = {'2008':['what!','@cool','#fog','@dddong'],'2010':['hey','@cute']}
>>> 
>>> def remove_punct(data):
...     import string
...     new_data = {} # the data we will return
...     punct = string.punctuation
...     rpunct = punct.replace('@',"") # withold @
...     for k,v in data.items():
...         new_data[k] = []
...         for word in data[k]:
...             new_data[k].append(word.strip(rpunct))
...     return new_data
... 
>>> remove_punct(dat)
{'2008': ['what', '@cool', 'fog', '@dddong'], '2010': ['hey', '@cute']}
```

Or in fewer lines:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> rpunct = punctuation.replace('@',"") # withold @
>>> new_data = {k: [word.strip(rpunct) for word in dat[k]] for k in dat}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting . AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @song0089 Yes, sorry about that. I edited the code since I was trying to call `append()` on the dictionary and not on the value, which is a list. It should work now.

Comment: Could you also help me with the second part? I tried using your logic to get rid of the words in the list, but I am not getting the result  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912483/how-to-remove-certain-words-within-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I used a different regex replacement for removing punctuations.

- \w will match alphanumeric characters and underscores
- [^\w] will match anything that's not alphanumeric or underscore

You don't even need to wrap it in a function, you can update the dict directly by using the code below:

```
import re

for key in dat.keys():
    dat[key] = [re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', i) for i in dat[key]]
```