# How to remove certain words within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values as list, each list includes strings. I want to 1) remove punctuations, excluding @ and 2) remove items in the list with '@'. Yet, I can't seem to get the second part:

```
>>> dat = {'2008':['what!','@cool','#fog','@dddong'],'2010':['hey','@cute']}
>>> 
>>> def remove_rounds(data):
...     import json
...     import string
...     ndata = {}
...     punct = string.punctuation
...     rpunct = punct.replace('@',"") # withold @
...     for k,v in data.items():
...         alist = []
...         ndata[k] = []
...         for word in data[k]:
...             alist.append(word.strip(rpunct))
...             ndata[k] = alist
...     sdata = {}
...     for k,v in ndata.items():
...         sdata[k] = []
...         blist = []
...         for word in ndata[k]:
...             if word.startswith('@'):
...                 blist = ndata[k].remove(word) # returns the list
...                 sdata[k] = blist
...     return sdata
... 
>>> remove_rounds(dat)
{'2008': None, '2010': None}
```

So, the `ndata` part worked okay, I was able to strip the punctuations in the lists, yet I can't seem to use the same logic to get rid of the words that starts with '@'. Also I don't get then why the same logic can't be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just avoid appending the word if it starts with `@`:

```
dat = {'2008':['what!','@cool','#fog','@dddong'],'2010':['hey','@cute']}

def remove_rounds(data):
    import string
    ndata = {}
    punct = string.punctuation
    rpunct = punct.replace('@',"") # withold @
    for k,v in data.items():
        alist = []
        ndata[k] = []
        for word in data[k]:
            if word.startswith("@"):
                continue # ignore this word and continue with the next one
            alist.append(word.strip(rpunct))
            ndata[k] = alist

    return ndata

print(remove_rounds(dat))
```

Result:

```
{'2008': ['what', 'fog'], '2010': ['hey']}
```

Comment: Oh wow, so you just ignore the words with '@' and then just remove the puncts for the others and append those. It makes sense.

Comment: @song0089 `ndata[k].remove(word)` modifies the list **inplace**, that means `ndata[k]` is changed, but the method returns `None`, so `blist` is `None` when you assign `sdata[k] = blist`.